# GeoPoint cant get my current Location and throws a java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

AM trying to access the device location using Geopoint but unfortunately am getting an error thrown is double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference and have read alot of tutorials but am still facing this problem

**Here is my code**

```
private void getLastKnownLocation() {

        if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            return;
        }

        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation ().addOnCompleteListener (new OnCompleteListener<Location> () {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {

                if ( task.isSuccessful () ) {
                    Location location = task.getResult ();
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint (location.getLatitude (),location.getLongitude ());
                    Log.d (TAG, "onComplete: latitude"+ geoPoint.getLatitude ());
                    Log.d (TAG, "onComplete: latitude"+ geoPoint.getLongitude ());

                }

            }
        });

    }
```

**The Error thrown**

- Process: com.aquaapp.gesfasta, PID: 23200
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
      at com.aquaapp.gesfasta.MuuzaMainActivity$1.onComplete(MuuzaMainActivity.java:107)
      at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6803)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getLastLocation()` can give you `null` value depending on availability. In this case you need to do call `requestLocationUpdates` and listen to any new location update.

Comment: You can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/get-current-location-using-fusedlocationproviderclient-in-android-cb7ebf5ab88e) for more information on this.